# Duration between two dates in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Is there a way in Groovy to get the duration between two Date objects? The duration format I'm looking for would be something like: 2 days, 10 hours, 30 minutes...

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[TimeCategory](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) has some methods for getting a duration. You could use it like

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def duration = date1 - date2
    print "Days: ${duration.days}, Hours: ${duration.hours}, etc."
}
```

Comment: @MichalBernhard How is using blocks considered "polluting"?

Comment: TimeCategory.minus(date1, date2).days

Comment: Please be aware that this can cause a miscalculation when entering daylight saving time(DST)/summer time. Since the time will skip an hour, it will calculate 0 days and 23 hours when you expect 1 day difference.

Comment: New link http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html

Answer (score 15):

The use()-Syntax is weird to me.
so I prefer it like this:

```
def duration = groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(
  new Date(),
  new Date(session.creationTime)
);
def values = [
            "seconds: " + duration.seconds,
            "min: " + duration.minutes,
            "hours: " + duration.hours,
            "days: " + duration.days,
            "ago: " + duration.ago,
];
```