# How to calculate difference between two date(date object) in Java

Tags: datetime, groovy

I have two date in form as:

```
date1 = Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 NPT 2013
date2 =  Tue Sep 30 00:00:00 NPT 2014
```

Now I need to find the difference between these two dates.

How can I do this in Java or in Groovy.

Comment: Did you do any research at all? Because if I paste your literal title into Google, it gives me useful results...

Comment: Actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755835/duration-between-two-dates-in-groovy badly tagged as Java

Answer (score 2):

Convert your dates to miliseconds and operate with them:

```
long diffInMills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

in seconds

```
diffInMills / 1000
```

in minutes

```
diffInMills / (1000*60)
```

in hours

```
diffInMills / (1000*60*60)
```

in days

```
diffInMills / (1000*60*60*24)
```