# is there Groovy code to get today date and compare with another input date?

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I want get the current date from the system(for eg- 2021-06-22) and compare with the input date  (for eg- 2021-06-22) in groovy code.I tried the below code but im getting error in month field.

```
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC');
  cal.setTimeZone(tz);
  int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)          //Get the hour from timestamp
  int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)                //Get the Minutes from timestamp     
  int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)
  int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
  int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE)
  int month= cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
  int year= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
​  println month
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duration between two dates in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755835/duration-between-two-dates-in-groovy)

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Do you want to get the difference by some time unit? Do you want to just see if the entered date is before or after today? Also: please ignore the answers on SO about Date or Calendar.  `java.time` is what is used nowadays.